# Using CMAKE and QT

Tags: linux, qt, cmake, fedora

everybody!

It's my first time using both Cmake and Qt and I'm having some trouble. This probably is some newb quest and is more related to linux than cmake and Qt, but I'm not sure.

I'm trying compile ScanTailor (https://github.com/scantailor/scantailor), but when I type `cmake .`, I get the following output

> -- Boost version: 1.55.0
>   -- Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/home/Igor/Documentos/github/scantailor/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "/home/Igor/Documentos/github/scantailor/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

I have installed Qt4, the path is `/lib64/qt4` , but how I tell that to cmake?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Is your QTDIR environment variable set?

Comment: @LahiruChandima Not the Qt4, i guess. '$QTDIR' will return '/usr/lib64/qt-3.3: Is a directory'. How do I change that?

Comment: If you are using bash, you can add these two lines to your `~/.bashrc`. `export QTDIR=/your/path/to/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64`.`export PATH=$QTDIR/bin:$PATH`. Then restart your terminal and check.

Comment: All that QTDIR stuff isn't necessary, but if it is set, it might interfere with cmake (call `unset QTDIR` before calling cmake). Also make sure you have the development packages including headers, qmake, etc. installed (they often come in separate qt-dev/qt-dev-tools packages). I'd try to build a simple hello world with qmake before continuing with cmake.

Comment: Why Qt4 is installed in /lib64/qt4? Did you install Qt using apt-get or something like that? I recommend you to insall Qt using the official package [link](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.6/)

Comment: Of course, after the installation, you must set the `QTDIR` environment variable: `export QTDIR=/path/to/Qt-4/`

Comment: @Coyote Do you steel need it? Can you post CMakeOutput.log and CMakeError.log?